# Handle signal without interrupting current sleep

Tags: perl, signals

In the below code, while sleeping if the QUIT signal comes the sleep will immediately finish and the last line of code will be executed.

```
#!/opt/tertio/localperl/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $quit = 0;

$SIG{'QUIT'} = sub { 
    print "Please dont try to take thread dump as i am not java\n"; 
    $quit++; 
};

my $sleep = shift || 30;
print "I am going to sleep\n";
sleep($sleep);

print "I woke up so will exit, but someone tried to quit me $quit times\n";
```

No matter how long I set the `sleep` time, as soon as I send a `QUIT` signal `sleep` ends and the program continues.

Is there a way to handle `QUIT` without affecting the current run of the program such that `sleep` continues for as long as it was meant to?

Comment: Put a loop around `sleep`.

Comment: but how would that allow the program to sleep for X amount of seconds then finish?

Comment: `while ($sleep > 0) { $sleep -= sleep($sleep); }`

Comment: ah the good old read the documentation. This was a quick example made to test/play with handling signals. reading the Perl doc for sleep it says `May be interrupted if the process receives a signal such as "SIGALRM".  Returns the number of seconds actually slept.  You probably cannot mix "alarm" and "sleep" calls, because "sleep" is often implemented using "alarm".`. So lesson learned. I just assumed the the alarm would interrupt the currently executed line of code. Seems its just cause i am using sleep that its interrupted

Comment: @melpomene: Please formulate an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up a block around that precious sleep, to ignore the signal within it

```
IGNORE_QUIT: {
    local $SIG{QUIT} = 'IGNORE';
    sleep 10;
};
```

If the `sleep` happens to already be scoped suitably then you don't need an extra block.

Can use a wrapper if there's more of this

```
sub sleep_protected {
    local $SIG{QUIT} = 'IGNORE';
    sleep $_[0];
}
```

The [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) is crucial  so that `$SIG{QUIT}` isn't changed globally but only within the block.

If you need a signal handler (and can't just use `'IGNORE'`) then `sleep` does get interrupted so that the handler can run. So you need to restart the call

```
sub sleep_protected {
    my $sl = $_[0];
    my $sigquit;
    local $SIG{QUIT} = sub { 
        say "Got $_[0], but don't do thread dump"; 
        ++$sigquit; 
    };
    $sl -= sleep $sl  while $sl > 0;
    return $sigquit;
}
```

The counter is local and returned but you can use a global one instead, declared with `our`. Or declare it as a [`state`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) variable and it is remembered across calls (see [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html)).

The interrupted call returns with error `EINTR` if interrupted by a signal. This can be checked for using [%!](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%!), as `if ($!{EINTR}) {...}`. However, I don't know how `sleep` can reasonably be interrupted other than by a signal and so didn't use this.